# Meaning of Latin expressions

Tags: from-the-latin

Please, can someone explain the meaning and give some examples of Latin expressions:

1. *'Quot generationes, tot gradus '*
2. *'Non omne quod licet honestum est' (and what's the difference between this expression and 'Male nostro iure uti non debemus'*
3. *'Actor sequitor forum rei'*
4. *'Nemo pro parte testatus, pro parte intestatus decedere potest'*

I Would be grateful for any help, thanks!

Comment: the first looks not fully Latin to me?!

Comment: I misspelled the word, I'm going to change. It should be 'Quot generationes, tot gradus'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The saying "*non omne quod licet honestum est*" refers to dishonesty that is not punishable by law. Laws purportedly prohibits or penalizes only the dishonesty which tends to --or does-- disrupt peace and order.

An example of legally harmless dishonesty is a scenario where you tell your neighbor his story is entertaining even though you think it is boring. By contrast, perjury is an example of harmful and punishable dishonesty because it tends to hinder the ascertainment of the truth and consequently the administration of justice.

The [meaning](https://deim.urv.cat/%7Eblas.herrera/regulaeiuris.html) of "*Male nostro iure uti non debemus*" is that one should refrain from abusing his rights. Strictly speaking, the expression contradicts itself since *abuse* and *right* have opposite connotations: One's exercise of his right implies that he has not exceeded the scope thereof, whence it cannot be said that the person abused his right.

In reality the expression refers to a person's acts or conduct which *knowingly* depart from the purpose for which the right was devised. The element of "*knowingly*" implies person's *dishonesty* insofar as he made an illegitimate use of his right.

Note that two or more of the phrases you list have misspellings or are incomplete, which might be preventing you from finding their meaning. For instance, "*uti*" is missing in your post. Also the first phrase should read [generationes](https://www.legal-lingo.net/quot-generationes-tot-gradus/), not *generations*.

Comment: I would suggest that this answer could be improved by replacing the ambiguous "sanction" which can mean both "accepted/permitted" and "penalized". Otherwise, +1.

Comment: @sharur Thank you! I was unaware of the former until now that you point it out.

Comment: The common theme of both sayings thus is "what you (legally) can do is not always what you (morally) should do"